# lagging cursor from magic mouse and magic trackpad

Tags: thunderbolt-display, magic-trackpad, mouse

I have a brand new mac mini 2012 connected to a Thunderbolt display. Since the Thunderbolt display was connected, I sometimes get a lagging cursor, meaning that moving the mouse/trackpad leads the cursor to follow the position very slowly. I have connected both, a Magic Mouse and a Magic Trackpad.

I'm trying to track down this issue but up to now, no avail. I've already connected another Magic Mouse, but same here.

Any idea welcome.

EDIT: if only the trackpad or the mouse is attached, it gets a bit better, but still not acceptable. I also moved around my WiFi-station and the Mac mini - not better.

Comment: I have the same issue. With bot my MacBook Pro (week old) as my MacBook Air. Just received a new thunderbolt cable. Still an issue.

Comment: thanks guys for your feedback. I'm still investigating. @Ramon: do you also have both, a Magic Mouse and a Magic Trackpad connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be radio interference. Try plugging in a usb mouse and see if you have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the hint with the radio interference, that seemed to be a large part of the problem.

In the end I did a lots of thing to get it going (consider it took like 6 hours all in all):

- I switched to cable network in that room (almost). WiFi and Bluetooth definitely where interacting negatively. BTW: cable networking feels so much better!
- the WiFi base-station was moved away from the Mac mini to the opposite side of the room.
- the Magic Trackpad is switched off most of the time. It looks like there is some kind of interference between Magic Mouse and Magic Trackpad.
- I deinstalled or updated any system preferences app, especially everything that has to do with GUI control.

Why I didn't move to a cable-mouse? I'm used to work with the swipe gesture a lot, and I'm not aware of a cable-mouse that understands Mac gestures.

Answer (score 0):

I've been experiencing the same issue, but with Dell Ultrasharp U2515H, MacBook Pro 13" and Magic mouse. Then I found out about [SmoothMouse](http://smoothmouse.com/). It's not resolve the issue completely but it helps.